# Infuriating issue with OS install on new motherboard

Tags: boot, motherboard, linux-mint, operating-systems, computer-building

This is the 4th “build” I’ve done and so far has been the most infuriating.

CPU: R5 3600 -> R7 5800X.
Motherboard: Asrock B450M Steel Legend -> B550M Steel Legend.

I also added another M.2 SSD, I quickly threw it together while forgetting to have an windows boot USB available. I did, however, have a Linux mint installer on a flash drive and decided to get started on Linux first (I’m new to Linux). Booted into mint and went through the installer to download it onto the empty M.2 and the installer finished, PC restarted, but it tried booting to my windows M.2 (still tied to old motherboard), and the new Linux installed M.2 wouldn’t even show up.

So I went back through and formatted the drive, and reinstalled Mint, same issue.
THEN after formatting the empty M.2 for NTFS, I formatted the USB on my laptop (through CMD -> disk part -> partition -> format) and put in windows media installer. Tried that, nothing, tried Ubuntu (yes I formatted it each and every time) and Ubuntu wouldn’t work. ONLY. MINT. [side note, while in mint, I could still see my files from my windows drive so I know they aren’t dead].

After a bit of yelling and breathing exercises I swap back only the necessary pieces into the old shell (old motherboard, old cpu) and booted with just the old windows M.2 and it wouldn’t boot, I’ll update with the error if I get back to this step. I took out that M.2 and put in the now, again, empty M.2 with the windows media USB and it took, and downloaded windows just fine.

What in hell is happening here? I almost wish I had a fried component, at least then I’d have a better idea of what I need to do but I’m lost.
**ANY HELP** is greatly appreciated. If you need any more information, I’ll do my best.

*EDIT: At this point I just want it to boot to windows, and worry about dual booting later.

Comment: You need to understand UEFI, its requirements and the boot process. When dual-booting Windows+Linux the first thing to do, in Windows, is to disable Fast Startup and shutdown properly, otherwise the desktop Linux installer may not "see" the Windows partitions. Of course, for both OSes ALWAYS use GPT and UEFI mode as this is the standard for more than a decade. Disable any "Legacy/CSM", end of story. Then, if after installing the desktop Linux it still boots Windows directly you may need to check UEFI > Boot and change the boot order to the entry identifying the Linux you just installed.

Comment: I’m not able to get it to boot to windows in the first place, is the main problem.

Comment: Again, you need to understand UEFI and its boot process. Namely you need to understand that you can - and at this point you should try - boot Windows directly from UEFI settings > Boot.

Comment: UEFI connects stores information needed to boot the OS in the UEFI [quasi bios].  This needs to be readded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but here's some things that might be getting in the way of booting.

1. You're UEFI chooses where to boot. It is often the case that it really tries to find and boot to Windows (the windows it boot to last time). It could be the case that you need to install mint/ubuntu, then specifically point the bios at Grub.
2. Partition table funnyness. Something that I've experienced is that the UEFI will or will not boot from MBR or GPT depending on if it's in BIOS compatibility/legacy mode or UEFI mode. That is to say, if it's in UEFI mode it only wants to boot to drives with a GPT partition table and if it's in legacy mode it doesn't want to boot to GPT drives.
3. Grub might be broken. There's this excellent little tool called [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) that can take care of some of those problems.
4. One time my computer straight up refused to boot to Ubuntu and I still don't know why. The fix was to go into the windows boot area, rename the windows bootloader, and move grub to the same spot and the same name as the windows bootloader had (secure boot needs to be off).

This sucks to deal with. Sorry you're havin a rough go at it. Hope this helps.